# Create scala filter conditions based on JSON in API gateway

Tags: scala, filter, apache-spark-sql

I am getting JSON filter conditions for Spark SQL. The JSON will be of the format:

```
{
    "x": {
        "LT": "2"
    }
}
```

Which should become like: `spark.sql("Select * from df where x < 2")`

Any idea how can I proceed? The data is read from parquet file using

```
spark.read.parquet(filePath)
```

So the code is as follows:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(filePath)
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
parse(filterJson).extract[Map[String, Any]]
// Once tables have been registered, you can run SQL queries over them.
for((k,v)<-Map){
  v match {
    case "EQ"=>"==="
    case "GT"=>">"
    case "LT"=>"<"
  }
}
df.filter(k)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you update the question with df.show output?

Comment: parquet is a file with around 1000 rows and 80 columns. Not sure why output is required..

Comment: I just wanted to see the sample and understand what you wanted to do as your question is a bit confusing.